# ManyToOne relation with existing entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm facing a new problem with Symfony and Doctrine. I have two entities Entity1 (ManyToOne) Entity2. In a page I have 2 forms, one form Entity1 newly created and an other form for Entity2 which can be already existing in the database. In every case, I want to attach Entity2 to Entity1. My problem arive when I want to attach an already existing Entity2 to Entity1. 
When I submit the form, in the database I have 2 entries, one with entity1 linked to the already existing entity2 (what I want) and an other one where it linked the same entity1 to a new instance of entity2 with a new id. I don't why I have that behavior.

First my entities :

```
class Entity2
{
    /**
    *@var int
    *
    *@ORM\Id
    *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     *@var Collection|Entity1[]
     *
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity1", mappedBy="entity2", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     *
     */
    private $entity1;
}

class Entity1
{
    /**
    *@var int
    *
    *@ORM\Id
    *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     *@var \Demandeur
     *
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity2", inversedBy="entity1", cascade={"persist"})
     *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idEntity2", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $entity2;
}
```

Originally, I had a cascade on persist also on OneToMany but I thought it was that causing my problem. 
Now my controller :

```
public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $ent1 = new Entity1();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $formEnt1 = $this->createForm(Entity1Type::class);    
        $formEnt1->handleRequest($request);

        $formEnt2 = $this->createForm(Entity2Type::class);
        $formEnt2->handleRequest($request);

        if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $ent1= $formEnt1->getData();

            $ent2 = new Entity2();
            $ent2 = $formEnt2->getData();
            $id = $request->request->get['id'];
            //if data already exist in database
            if($id > 0) {
                $ent2 ->setId($id);
                $dem = $em->merge($ent2);
                //attach the existing entity2 to entity1
                $ent1Ent2 = $em->merge($ent1->setDemandeur($ent2));
             }else{
                //attach the new entity2 to entity1
                $ent1->setEntity2($ent2 );
             }     
            $em->persist($ent1);
            $em->flush();  
            return ...
}
```

Also I am not sure I am using the merge() function correctly. What am I missing and obviously doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of `$dem = $em->merge($ent2);` you should do `$ent2 = $em->merge($ent2);`. Merge returns the managed entity, `$ent2` is (unless you use my approach) still the new unmanaged entity, which will be persisted as a new entity. id is still a generated value too. I don't even grasp, what your `$ent1Ent2` is supposed to be though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it and I don't have a new ent2 created but there is still 2 ent1 created... My $ent1Ent2 is that I want to set the existing Ent2 entity to the new Ent1. Since I underdstood your explanation with the merge functions, I correted my $ent1Ent3 to $ent1 and everything is working ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to put this question as solved, I'll describe the solution given by @Jakumi in the comment section. 
My mistakes was with the merge() function I used in a wrong way. I had to write :

```
$ent2 = $em->merge($ent2);
$ent1 = $em->merge($ent2->setDemandeur($ent1));
```

With those I get a new entity1 linked to an existing entity2.